# How to install Intel Graphics drivers for Mint 13

Tags: linux-mint, graphics, intel, graphic-card

I have choppy video and my windows are choppy when I move them around. Also when my PC turns off monitor it does not turn off normally but like the cable was unplugged. I guess I need to install a driver for my new 'graphics' chip. Can someone please provide the 'best' way of installing graphics drivers for my Celeron G1820 CPU.

Here is what I get from `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

I can provide any additional info if needed.

Comment: Check `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and see what driver X is currently using.

Answer (score 0):

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+
|intel Gen4|OpenGL 2.1|OpenGL ES2|OpenCL NO |  VAAPI   |i965  |
|          |          |          |          |Only MPEG2|Kernel|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------+
```

You should Install `xf86-video-intel` a binary package containing driver for all Intel GPU Chipsets.
Because I don't know the exact nature of your problem (whether it is the driver, Kernel module, or Xorg Configuration) I cant recommend any additional steps. But it's worth mentioning that `Xorg config` file and `modeset` in Grub are also places to look at.

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong. because the Intel driver on Mint should work out of the box. first update your repos and also your mint then go for the solution.

Comment: sudo modprobe i965

Comment: `sudo modprobe i965`
WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/.
FATAL: Module i965 not found.

Comment: @mbiber install the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: It's installed already

Answer (score 0):

Add Intel Repository :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/12.04/main Ubuntu 12.04" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intel-graphics.list'
```

Then download and install the GPG key via 2 commands:

```
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

and

```
wget https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

install Intel Graphics Driver:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install intel-linux-graphics-installer
```