# Intel graphics driver for Linux Mint 17

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, intel-graphics

I just purchased a new pc and decided to install Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit

- Intel CPU: i7 4790 (1150/3.6GHz/8MB)
- Motherboard: MSI Z97 Gaming 5 (1150/Z97/DDR3) No external graphic card

The problem is that I can't install drivers for graphics and sound.

In my System info (or $ lcpci) I get:

- Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller

Can someone please tell me how to install these drivers.

Comment: Please see this reply:

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118769/how-to-install-intel-graphics-drivers-for-mint-13

The link above is for graphics, please provide lspci output for audio and please copy paste the whole line, I am sure lspci does not print "Graphics Card:"

Comment: @thecarpy You link to a post that has two replies neither of which work as they have not been accepted and neither even have a vote. I am facing a similar issue and would like an appropriate answer for this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297627/3d-graphics-drivers-for-xeon-e3-1200-3-4th-on-board-graphics-card if you can help

Comment: @jamesw You are correct with the answers not being accepted, however, often, people just ask, get the answer and forget to vote for the best answer.

Could you please post lspci in full ?
Also, have you installed xserver-xorg-video-intel ? If so, then please look at /var/log/Xserver.0.log. What does dmesg say ?

Also see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics

    Make sure you do not have nomodeset or vga= as a kernel parameter, since Intel requires kernel mode-setting.
    Also, check that you have not disabled Intel by using any modprobe blacklisting.